# images in different spans, 1 is clickable/linkable

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, html

I have the following problem: I run a blog http://androidawesomeness.com, where I have three socialmedia account images underneath my headerlogo. I want all images to link to the relevant social media account, but I just seem to get one image clickable/linkable, the other two aren't.

Could you guys help me out and tell me what the problem is? This is my HTML:

```
<span id="socialmediag">
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/109829575107956373311">
  <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3M1z0a0t08293Y1L3k0u/google-plus-logo-aa.png" alt="google-plus-logo" width="15" height="15" />
 </a>
</span>

<span id= 'socialmediatw'>
 <a href="https://www.twitter.com/androidawsumnes">
  <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3j1A2V0z3M1O2v0A0B2P/twitter-logo-aa.png" alt="twitter-logo-aa" width="17" height="15" />
 </a>
</span>

<span id='socialmediatu'>
 <a href="http://www.androidawesomeness.tumblr.com">
  <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/320c1g0n39060j091l2g/tumblr-logo-aa.png" alt="tumblr-logo-aa" width="15" height="15" />
 </a>
</span>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#socialmediag{
position: absolute;
padding: 8px 3px 0px 30px;}

#socialmediatw{
position: absolute;
padding: 8px 3px 0px 110px;}

#socialmediatu{
position: absolute;
padding: 8px 3px 0px 190px;}
```

Thanks!
NOTE: I'm quite new to this so please be gentle with me.

Comment: Each span has crazy padding, which overlaps each other span, preventing you from clicking on the link

Comment: Is that a typo? `<imgsrc`? Should be `<img src`

Comment: I think you tried to fix, but it's now `<imgs rc=` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using padding to position. That changes the actual size of the elements, and because you're absolute positioning, they will overlap, and the last one is in front of the others (so they're not 'clickable'). The quick fix is to change padding to margin. The better fix is to delete padding and replace with `top: 8px;` and `left: your-left-padding-value-for-this-element;`.

Comment: Thanks! For your answer but also for your explanation. When I used firebug I saw an overlay while on the Tumblr logo. But I couldn't figure out what the solution was. Now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way you use padding to move the images is making the element larger. As such, the Tumblr link covers the Twitter link and the G+ link, and the Twitter one also covers the G+ link. Since you're using `position:absolute;` you can simply say `left:190px;` for Tumblr (and similarly 110px and 30px for the others) instead of changing the left padding, and that'll reposition the element without enlarging it.

Comment: If you position in one direction, it's a good idea to position in the other (eg. `left: xxx;`, add a `top` or `bottom` positioning). IE8 and lower don't like just the single axis. IIRC IE9+ can handle it (and most everything else).

Comment: Good call -- I'd go with `top:8px;` and abandon the padding as you suggest in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each span's padding is overlapping each other element, and preventing you from clicking on them.

As a quick fix, you could get away with this instead

```
#socialmediag{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 3px 0px 0px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
#socialmediatw{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 3px 0px 0px;
  margin-left:110px;
}
#socialmediatu{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 3px 0px 0px;
  margin-left:190px;
}
```

But to be honest, you don't really need absolute positioning there at all which is what caused the issue, and i'd suggest trying to not use it.

**Edit:**

Although i can see your page has a fair bit of absolute positioning in use, so i'm guessing you're not that comfortable with using otherwise which is fine.

But just for clarity sake, you could have one class instead applied to all 3 elements, and it would produce the same effect, something like this.

```
.socialmedia {
  float:left;
  margin: 10px 45px 0px 20px;
}
```

I'd recommend looking into using float, especially if you're new to this, as it'll save you so much time later on!

Comment: Absolute positioning isn't what's causing the issue, the padding is. Removing absolute positioning and keeping the margins you describe would actually worsen the problem.

Comment: @DavidMillar I didn't suggest to remove the absolute positioning AND keeping the margins. I suggested to move away from using that kind of CSS all together and move onto a completely different solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the styles you have written and add the following in your CSS anywhere.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
}
#socialmediag, #socialmediatw, #socialmediatu {
    top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}
#socialmediag {
    left: 30px;
}
#socialmediatw {
    left: 112px;
}
#socialmediatu {
    left: 190px;
}
```